# Could a DataGridView allow only System Generated inputs and disable manual input?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView `dgv1` and I would populate it programmatically. However, I would like to block User Input to it but it should be visible to the user.

As far as I've known, DataGridView property `AllowUserToAddRows` can do this. However, it also allows the user inputs.

How should I resolve this? or Should I use another control?

Comment: @GrantWinney thank you for the quick response! It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable editing by the user for an entire `DataGridView`, set the [ReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
dgv1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. That's why I posted because I can't find one.